# Выборка из БД по нескольким полям

Tags: sql, база-данных, sql-server, запрос, select

Имеется следующая структура данных:

[image: Схема данных]

Необходимо составить запрос и вывести следующие поля:

1. "Name"
2. "Office"
3. Сумма часов сотрудника
4. Сумма часов офиса
5. Доля часов сотрудника в офисе (п.3 / п.4)

Сделал до п.4:

```
SELECT Employee.Name, Employee.Office, SUM(Work.Hours) AS EMP_hours
FROM Employee 
INNER JOIN Work ON Employee.ID = Work.EmpID
GROUP BY Employee.Name, Employee.Office
```

Отдельно п.4:

```
 SELECT Employee.Office,SUM(Hours) 
 FROM Work 
 INNER JOIN Employee ON Employee.ID = EmpID 
 GROUP BY Office
```

---

Вопросы:

1. А как это совместить в одном запросе?
2. Как правильно сделать п.5 ?

Comment: Пожалуйста, публикуйте данные как текст, а не картинки. Их будет легче копировать для теста.

Comment: Добавьте структуру таблицы **Hours**

Comment: Исправил ошибку: вместо Hours - Work

Comment: @MaxMalahov вроде тоже самое в двух разных выборках. Часы у Employee только в таблице Work?

Comment: @KostaB. Да, только там

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT Employee.Name, Employee.Office, SUM(Work.Hours) AS EMP_hours,
       SUM(SUM(Work.Hours)) over(partition by Employee.Office) AS Office_hours,
       SUM(Work.Hours) / SUM(SUM(Work.Hours)) over(partition by Employee.Office) AS percentage
  FROM Employee 
 INNER JOIN Work ON Employee.ID = Work.EmpID
 GROUP BY Employee.Name, Employee.Office
```

Тут используются [оконные функции](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/sql/t-sql/queries/select-over-clause-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017), которые работают после группировки запроса и могут использовать как параметры результаты агрегирующих функций для их укрупнения в другом разрезе.

Comment: Спасибо, все здорово. Только **percentage** почему то не считается

Comment: @MaxMalahov Что значит "не считается" ? может у вас часы хранятся в целочисленном типе и поэтому суммы то же целочисленные и при делении конечно никакой дробной части появится не может и выходит 0 ? Если так, то лечится приведением к дробному числу `(sum(Work.Hours)+0.0) /
       sum(sum(Work.Hours)) over(partition by Employee.Office)`

Comment: Вы абсолютно правы! Спасибо!

Comment: @MaxMalahov Тогда отметьте ответ как принятый (зеленая галочка под рейтингом ответа)